# Как отключить инерцию у ScrollView?

Tags: android

Если отпустить палец, некоторое время скролирование продолжается по инерции. Как отключить этот эффект? 
На stackoverflow писали задать `scrollView.setSmoothScrollingEnabled(false)`  но мне не помогло.

Comment: Хы, в своё время перешёл с as3 на java именно потому, что запарился в попытках написать свою реализацию именно инерции для списка на as3)

Comment: Можно, если тачи самим обрабатывать.

Answer (score 2):

Боюсь, что никак. Судя по исходникам `ScrollView`, за это отвечает `android.view.VelocityTracker`, инициализация которого в `ScrollView` происходит в приватных методах. И переопределить его нет никакой возможности.

Comment: зря вы боитесь. все можно :)